# Gradle sub module compileOnly function not exists

Tags: kotlin, gradle, compilation

My app build.gradle.kts

[image]

My root settings.gradle.kts

[image]

My root build.gradle.kts

[image]

```
Build file '/home/gutyerrez/Documents/Hyren Network/core/build.gradle.kts' line: 1

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply {
        plugin("org.springframework.boot")
        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    }
}
```